# sectionNameKeyPath through multiple relationships

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am working on an app that uses Core Data and an `NSFetchedResultsController`.  The model setup is like this:

```
/-----------\          /-----------\          /-----------\
|Part       |          |Kit        |          |Source     |
|-----------|          |-----------|          |-----------|
|name       |          |name       |          |name       |
|dimensions |          |description|          |location   |
|...        |          |...        |          |...        |
|-----------|          |-----------|          |-----------|
|kits       | <<-\     |source     | <<-----1 |kits       |
|           |     \->> |parts      |          |           |
\-----------/          \-----------/          \-----------/
```

So, a `Part` has a many-to-any relationship with a `Kit` (a part can be in one or more kits, and a kit can contain one or more parts).  And each `Kit` comes from a `Source` which may provide one or more `Kit`s.

I am currently creating a `UITableView` that uses an `NSFetchedResultsController` with a simple listing of all of the `Part` objects.  I would like to group the parts into sections, with each section being a `Source`'s name.  I.e.:

```
|-------------------------------|
|Source One                     |
|-------------------------------|
|Part One                       |
|Part Two                       |
|Part Three                     |
|-------------------------------|
|Source Two                     |
|-------------------------------|
|Part Four                      |
|Part Two                       |
|Part Five                      |
|....                           |
|-------------------------------|
|             O                 |
|-------------------------------|
```

Since a `Part` may come from multiple `Source`s, is it possible to do this with an NSFetchedResultsController by using the sectionNameKeyPath, or do I have to do this a completely different way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, because the `NSFetchedResultsController` won't know which `Kit` to use to sort `Part`s by, since it's a many-many relationship.

Think of a tree view, or even Objective-C inheritance structure, where each child node has exactly one parent, but itself can have many children nodes. You can easily recurse up the tree from the child node up to its parent. But if a child could have many parents, it wouldn't intrinsically know which parent to choose when recursing up the "tree" (which is more like a graph now).

So in your data model, does the `Part`s have to have many `Kit`s? Because if you change the many-many relationship between `Kit` and `Part` to a to-many relationship, where a `Kit` can have many `Part`s, but a `Part` can have only one Kit, then you could set the `sectionNameKeyPath` on `NSFetchedResultsController` to `@"kit.source.name"` to sort by name, and everything would work fine.

Of course I don't know exactly how your app works, if you do really need a many-many relationship between `Kit` and `Part`, but if you do, then you probably would not be able to use an `NSFetchedResultsController`, and would have to implement fetching `Source`s and implementing the `UITableViewDataSource` methods yourself :(

Answer (score 0):

You can get this result using NSFetchedResultsController for Many to Many relationships

See this answer: How to deal with many to many relationships with NSFetchedResultsController?

And example project: https://github.com/dmathewwws/Many-to-Many-CoreData